# Post CV for Feedback?

Tags: discussion, jobs, cv

Would meta be the proper place to ask for feedback on a CV?  Are there existing threads where job seekers do this?

Comment: Others have done so (including a MSO moderator) - whether or not it's appropriate is debatable. I have no problem with it - on Meta people mostly like to help each other out.

Answer (score 7):

It sounds to me like this might be a new opportunity for the Careers site to go in this direction (by adding a question-and-answer area dedicated to "help me with my career" questions).

After all, we close a *lot* of career advice-type questions on SO, so it might be an interesting experiment to give these posts a home.

Comment: +1 Spin up a StackExchange and pop it right in.

Comment: WaterCoolerOverflow?

Comment: IsMyCVHotOtNot.com

Comment: Hmmm, community-edited CVs - sounds like fun.

Comment: can i comment here?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for advice on the content of your CV, then no.  If you've got a technical request or problem on the site then go nuts.  I personally don't know of any sites that offer feedback, though.  I'm sure that there are career planning sites / forums out there.

Answer (score 0):

There are *so* many *great* resources for job and career advice (many free services are probably local to you) that it would be doing you a disservice to pretend that Meta is a good source for such information and advice.

Comment: OTOH, there are probably plenty of people here with specific responsibilities in hiring for software jobs, so it might be worth a shot.

Comment: Also, the CV posting here seems (at least to me) like it's a bit non-traditional.  So it would be more about getting feedback on the stack overflow CV, and how it might look to employers who use this site vs. general (traditional) CV feedback.

Comment: Has anyone created a ForJobs/OnJobs/HelpMeGetAJob StackExchange yet?  It could do well in the current job environment.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Stack Exchange site for careers: [Careers Advice](http://advice.personforce.com/). You could try asking there.